# What does コピー mean here?

Tags: meaning

There isn't really much context to the word コピー here, so I am inserting the whole page of the manga. I understand the basic meanings of コピー, which are pretty much the same as the English copy, but I have no idea how to translate it here. The screaming girl is Yozora. Her older sister is held back a grade and they will both end up in the same grade next year. I think コピー refers to the phrase 姉と同級生なんて嫌だ。 Yozora hasn't used the phrase before, nor has any other character. Do you have any idea what コピー might mean here?

[image: Haganai 19, page 167]

Edit: The name of the manga is 僕は友達が少ない volume 19 (English title: Haganai I have few friends).
Based on a light novel by Yomi Hirasaka 平坂読.
Manga author: Itachi いたち.
Art by Buriki ブリキ.
Published by MFC MFコミックス, Kadokawa.

As requested in a comment I am also including the previous page.
[image: Haganai 19, page 166a]
[image: Haganai 19, page 166b]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Her older sister was held up". Held up how? Also can we see the previous page please?

Comment: I'd guess that it refers to the picture being copied, i.e., being used twice.

Comment: @EddieKal I think they're referring to "held up a grade", meaning she's going to 留年

Comment: @Shurim Interesting. I've never heard "held up a grade", only "held back a grade".

Comment: Is it part of a commercially published manga, or in the case of an amateur work, published online somewhere? If so, I suggest including credits (the name of the author, the name of the work, the URL, etc). In general, it's a good practice to quote things with proper credits, and it could provide less obvious context that might help.

Comment: Possibilities: 1. Prepproduction draft annotation for internal editing made its way into production; 2. what looks like コ is bodily fluid, ピー is onomatopoeia; 3. what looks like コ is an instruction to the editors to indicate "replace following ピー with machine printing" (but the editors missed it); 4. inside joke implicitly indicating "this is an hommage from **that** scene" - e.g. Gintama, Yo-kai Watch, etc. does this often.

Comment: @Eddie Kal Of course it shoud have been "held back", sorry, I'm not a native English speaker, my mistake.

Comment: @Yusuke Matsubara Thank you for the info! It is a published manga: 僕は友達が少ない. I will add the full information in the main post.

Comment: @Dungarian Thank you for your comment. I think this might be the 4th possibility, the inside joke. It makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This コピー does look odd to me, too, but コピー rarely refers to saying the same thing twice. This コピー may be referring to the picture rather than the text. This is possibly a note from the author, something like "You know, this picture is a xeroxed one from a previous episode/book". (In general, something like this does not necessarily mean the author was lazy, but I don't know about this specific title.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I think you might be right, the コピー might refer to the image, not the text. I will look at previous volumes to find where exactly it might be from.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this just the character calling the other person a copy-cat? As in doin the same thing?